# ci/cd "docker" command not found in image built with docker installed

Tags: docker, gitlab, dockerfile, gitlab-ci.yml

I have this .gitlab-ci.yml file wanting to automate the docker image building, basically I'm using the one from the template:

```
docker-build:
  image: my_image_build_with_docker_inside_inprivate_repo
  stage: build
  services:
    - docker:dind
  before_script:
    - docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" -p "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" $CI_REGISTRY
  # Default branch leaves tag empty (= latest tag)
  # All other branches are tagged with the escaped branch name (commit ref slug)
  script:
    - |
      if [[ "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH" == "$CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH" ]]; then
        tag=""
        echo "Running on default branch '$CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH': tag = 'latest'"
      else
        tag=":$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG"
        echo "Running on branch '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH': tag = $tag"
      fi
    - docker build --pull -t "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE${tag}" .
    - docker push "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE${tag}"
  # Run this job in a branch where a Dockerfile exists
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
      exists:
        - Dockerfile
```

#$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE = my_image_build_with_docker_inside_inprivate_repo

When I run it get this error:

```
$ docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" -p "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" $CI_REGIST
/bin/bash: line 132: docker: command not found
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

With : RUN apt-get install -y [docker-compose](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/docker-compose) , I get everything needed for docker to run in the debian image. But I still get the error of docker command not found as above. What are the other steps needed to run docker daemon from your custom image?

Update: From the private repository, pushing images with docker installed is not allowed either. Looks like I have to use something called kaniko. Any good resource for this?

Comment: Could you add the list of images that it shows?

Comment: Yes, I added it

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing docker in the `Dockerfile` to build your custom image.

You can follow the steps defined in the official docs https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/debian/ which would look like something like this in your `Dockerfile`

```
RUN apt-get install -y \
    ca-certificates \
    curl \
    gnupg \
    lsb-release
RUN curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg
RUN echo \
  "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian \
  $(lsb_release -cs) stable" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io docker-compose-plugin
```

Comment: I actually tried that, I just added : RUN apt-get install -y docker-compose , which in the Debian image installs everything needed for docker to run. But even with that I get the error, docker not found. Is there something else needed to run docker form the actual custom image?

Comment: It seems that the docker package in debian is not actually docker https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/docker

I would install it as the official docs recommend or using the https://get.docker.com/ script if your are fine with executing this script as root.

Comment: The actual package is this: https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/docker-compose , I can run every docker command after installing just that

Comment: and you are running the exact same debian version as the one in the docker container? that is werid then

Comment: in any case, you can try installing the `docker.io` package which is the one that actually contains the `docker` binary. `docker-compose` package has it as a recommended dependency and it may be that for some reason it is not being installed in your container

Comment: wait, but do I need to install docker on a separate image, or the image which actually hold my python app and which I'm trying to rebuild each time?

Comment: The `my_image_build_with_docker_inside_inprivate_repo` image is the one that should have docker installed

Comment: looks like I can't push an image with docker installed in this private repo

Comment: I would have to use something called kaniko for this to run